# ExceptionInInitializerError when querying a collection using querydsl

Tags: java, querydsl

When executing the following code I get an exception when executing the query/projection. Does anybody know what I am doing incorrectly? All help greatly appreciated.

```
Data lt = alias(Data.class,"Data");

for(String location: from ($(lt),Arrays.asList(allData.toArray())).list($(lt.getData()))){
    System.out.println(location);
}
```

The Exception I get is as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at com.mysema.query.collections.MiniApi.(MiniApi.java:22)... etc.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mysema.codegen.EvaluatorFactory.(EvaluatorFactory.java:51)
>       at com.mysema.query.collections.ExprEvaluatorFactory.(ExprEvaluatorFactory.java:55)
>       at com.mysema.query.collections.ExprEvaluatorFactory.(ExprEvaluatorFactory.java:50)
>       at com.mysema.query.collections.ExprEvaluatorFactory.(ExprEvaluatorFactory.java:32)
>       ... 4 more

Comment: Could you try the same with the latest version of Querydsl and file a bug if it isn't fixed. The given stacktrace is related to an older version of Querydsl.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Data class has an empty constructor. I am currently on vacation and don't have the sources to investigate the stacktrace further, but adding the empty constructor would be my first thing to try.

The alias feature of Querydsl generates dynamic subclasses, and this fails for classes without an empty non-private constructor.

Comment: Thanks Timo for answering from the Beach! Living the Dream..... Unfortunately I had already ensured that the default parameterless constructor was empty. There are however other public constructors which are not empty. The class files were generated by Hibernate although for the purposes of this test I was not using them in conjunction with the querydsl hibernate classes. I was merely seeing how to query normal every collections of in memory objects. Thanks for your time.

Comment: conrad-rowlands, Have you been able to find a solution?